# Suspicious request after logging in

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts

I just logged in on the main site (with MyOpenId), and after being logged in successfully, I got a page that read:

> Suspicious request
>
> Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked
>   suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Travel Answers,
>   please return to the previous page and try again

Comment: You are a bit, wearing a mask... Suspicious to me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon investigation, this was a race condition between two log in requests.

My hunch is that you opened the log in page in a separate tab and logged in manually from that.
In the meanwhile the original page auto-magically logged you in via JavaScript. This invalidated the manual request.

In any case it's quite unrelated to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170875).

Comment: Yes, this could very well be. I did open the login in a separate tab.

Comment: ... seeing your edit; I do think this is a bug and could potentially be critical.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was [raised on Meta StackOverflow earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170875/164542).

> We don't usually require sticky IPs (in particular once you're logged
>   in it shouldn't be an issue), but if during the process of logging in
>   your IP address changes, that's extremely fishy, and that's why we
>   bail out.

So essentially this happens if/when your IP address changes during the login process and this is probably an issue at your ISP level.

Comment: Sounds unlikely, since the connection would have been gone briefly. Additionally, the site actually logged me in, so it did *not* "bail out".