# Certificate error while loading site for first time

Tags: support

I used chrome to access the website for first time and it says "This site's security certificate is not trused" and this site is meta.travel.stackexchange whereas the certificate is from *.stackexchange.com. I need to click proceed to open the website.

I tried to visit the site from google result for this url,

> https://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/suspicious-request-after-logging-in

and redirected to this url,

```
https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/suspicious-request-after-logging-in
```

Other stackexchange sites don't show this message.

Chrome: 59 version